# Override number sequence in pasting

Tags: string, r, escaping, sequence

I am trying to create a name using `paste()` for saving a file; this name will be in part composed out of the *sequence of dates* used to create the data frame to be saved.

So, I wish the output to be a string of `"./Calculations (Raw)/ 1:2 - 3.csv"`.

The first part refers to the path, which works by itself, and the `.csv` to the file extension appended.

```
Road <- 1
Dates <- 1:2
paste("./Calculations (Raw)/", Dates , "-" , Road, ".csv")
```

Problem is, that code produces *two* strings, breaking the `write.csv`.

How can I override the number sequence?

Comment: Use `Dates <- "1:2"`, i.e. as a string. To produce the string programmatically you could use `paste0(Dates, collapse=":")`

Comment: @MarkHeckmann Somehow I kept using as.character without it working. That works, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized.  You need to `collapse` your `dates` vector to length 1, which you can do with the `collapse` argument to `paste`:

```
paste("./Calculations (Raw)/", paste(Dates, collapse="-") , "-" , Road, ".csv")
# [1] "./Calculations (Raw)/ 1-2 - 1 .csv"
```

If you don't do this, `paste` will extend all the vectors to the length of the longest vector (in this case `Dates`), and only then `paste` them, which is why you end up with multiple values instead of just one.

As an aside, you probably also want to change the `sep` argument to `paste` so you don't end up with spaces in your file names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `1:2` as it is, create a string, i.e., `"1:2"`.

```
Road <- 1
Dates <- "1:2"
paste("./Calculations (Raw)/", Dates , "-" , Road, ".csv")
# [1] "./Calculations (Raw)/ 1:2 - 1 .csv"
```